# I can approve tag wiki revisions

Tags: discussion, review

I have just approved of a [proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1810) to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/biometrics/info) of [biometrics](/questions/tagged/biometrics).

But I don’t have editing privileges for this tag myself so I’m not sure that I should be allowed to give approval to edits to it.

**EDIT** I’m not sure if my approval actually came through. SilentGhost has edited the wiki in the meantime. I should mention that right after my approval, the tag wiki was unchanged but my approval vote *was* logged by the system. Which would be worse: I’m not allowed to grant approval for edits I’m not privileged to make myself (good) but my approval will still remove the edit from the review queue so that nobody else will be able to approve it. Uhm? (Am I making sense at all here?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over 20k users can edit any tag wiki:

> Users with 20000 reputation or more can always edit all tag wikis

That's what an empty tag info pages says.

It wasn't appearing as edited, because there was no excerpt. I think. Once I added the excerpt, the wiki appeared. I also saw the wiki excerpt in queue, but I think it was reject before you managed to approve it.

Comment: @jinguy: I don't know. I've discovered it when the biometrics wiki come up in queue :)

Comment: @jjn Yes, it is a brand new feature. It was just rolled out today.